# How to invoke Spring channel adapter from rest api?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am new to Spring integration. I have a JDBC inbound channel adapter as below. When the spring boot application starts below adapater is invoked and starts reading from DB. But i want below to be invoked only after REST API is called

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter query="select * from accounts" data-source="dataSource" max-rows-per-poll="100" row-mapper="AccountsRowMapper" channel="Accountchannel">

and below rest api as below

@GetMapping(value = "/generateFile")  
public void generateFile(String region)   
{  
// invoked above adapater only after this API is called
}
```

I am unable to understand how to start reading from DB only after generateFile API is invoked
I am not sure how to

Answer (score 0):

The Inbound Channel Adapter is a thing by itself and it does its work via constant polling cycle. It just does not fit to your requirement.

Since you say you'd like to do something via REST call, then it is an event-driven by end-user action. Therefore you need to look into a `<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>` instead which is going to receive a message via its `input-channel` and do some DB action and produce a reply for you.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-outbound-gateway.

In addition you may look into a `@MessagingGateway` contract to not deal with channels in your REST controller: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway