# How to write jdbc inbound channel adapter programmatically to read data from DB and pass to output channel?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am new to spring integration and i want to write the below flow programmatically

I have below inbound channel adapter in which I query the DB and passing it to OutChannel
and from OutChannel to AccountOutputChannel. AccountOutputChannel has refernce of a class which calls onMessage when message is available on AccountOutputChannel

How can I do this all programmatically

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="jdbcInbound"
                                      channel="OutChannel"
                                      data-source="dataSource"
                                      query="SELECT * FROM Accounts"
                                      max-rows-per-poll="100"
                                      row-mapper="AccountRowMapper">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
    </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="OutChannel"/>

<int:bridge input-channel="OutChannel" output-channel="AccountOutputChannel"/>

<int:channel id="AccountOutputChannel">
   <int:dispatcher task-executor="executorPool"/>
</int:channel>

<int:service-activator input-channel="AccountOutputChannel" ref="AccountService" method="onMessage"/>
```

Comment: I think the answer to your question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75307260/how-to-invoke-spring-channel-adapter-from-rest-api: the `<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>` is what you need in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

See similar question here: [How to invoke Spring channel adapter from rest api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75307260/how-to-invoke-spring-channel-adapter-from-rest-api)

The Inbound Channel Adapter is a thing by itself and it does its work via constant polling cycle. It just does not fit to your requirement.

Since you say you'd like to do something via REST call, then it is an event-driven by end-user action. Therefore you need to look into a `<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>` instead which is going to receive a message via its `input-channel` and do some DB action and produce a reply for you.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-outbound-gateway.

In addition you may look into a `@MessagingGateway` contract to not deal with channels in your REST controller: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway